Words with a permanent definite article
I know that English has some words which always use "the" article like: the past/present/future, the truth, the same, the process, the end, the way, the (name) language, the (name) religion etc.
I looked around the Cambridge dictionary a bit, the word "process" and I can't understand these sentences:

Increasing the number of women in top management jobs will be a slow
process.

I don't get it how "slow process" can be general/unknown when we have some words that they can specify the meaning like "the number of women in top management jobs". If we know so, then we must know which process is about.

The party has begun the painful (= difficult) process of rethinking
its policies and strategy.

How can this process be specific/defined if the previous sentence use "a slow process"? By this logic, it should go like this: "The party has begun a painful process of rethinking its policies and strategy". I'm so confused.
I asked ChatGPT, and it's too abstract about terms like "general" and "specific" in the context of articles
I'm trying to learn from context but it just doesn't work. I want to solve the article issue once and for all to not bother you.

Sorry, that's a fool's errand.  There is no simple rule to learn, or list of words to memorize.

We use the definite article when we're singling out the process itself. So when it's the subject that's modified by a prepositional phrase, we use "the process of ...".
We also use "the" when we're identifying a specific process out of multiple. E.g.

There are many steps involved in improving diversity. Increasing the number of women in management is the slow process.

But if we're only describing a previously mentioned item, we use the indefinite article as in your example.
It's similar to other nouns. Consider the difference between

I live in a red house on Main Street.

and

I live in the red house on Main Street.

The first describes my house as being red, while the second identifies my house as the only red one.

The words you list do not always take the definite article.
As far as I know there are no words like that, with the trivial exception of proper nouns where the article is part of the name.
Let's take "process" as an example. Here are two correct sentences:

The company needs to reduce the number of employees, and has already started the process to do so.


The company has started a process that will result in better profitability.

The first sentence is talking about one identified process (reducing the number of employees) and so uses the definite article.
The second sentence does not specify what the process is (there are many different processes that can better profitability) so it takes an indefinite article.
Here's another for the word "end":

I had difficulty starting to untangle the string, but now I have found an end it will be easier.

Strings have two ends, and we neither know nor care which was found, so we use the indefinite article.
There are well known phrases that back this up: Saying "It's a process" means that a lot of steps have to be carried out to reach the goal. "Make an end of it" means to finish something.
With your example you could reasonably use either the definite or indefinite articles. In "the painful process of rethinking its policies and strategy" it is assumed that the description ("rethinking its policies and strategy") conveys enough information to specify what the process is: making it unique and thus needing the definite article. But if you said: "The party has begun a painful process which it hopes will result in victory in the next election" that does not uniquely specify the process; many processes could result in that. Since the process isn't specified the indefinite article is used.

The simplest rule is: the is specific, a is not:
Sample: Increasing the number of women in top management jobs will be a slow process.= It will be a slow process to increase the number of women in top management jobs. The process will take time.
See how it switches? From general to specific. It's the word process that is slow and then it becomes specific.
I saw a dog in the street. The dog was black.
Sometimes, it depends on what you mean or want to say:
The party has begun a painful (= difficult) process of rethinking its policies and strategy. This is a generality.
The party has begun the painful (= difficult) process of rethinking its policies and strategy. This is specific, suggesting the process is known.
(Yes, there are some cases referring to local or single ideas or matters, where we use the rather systematically. Also, if there is only one of something:

I went to the school to see the principal.
The mayor was not in his office.
The universe is said to be huge in size.

Compare:

I went to a school where there were no books.
A mayor's job is hard.
Can you imagine a universe that is not huge?


We often use "the" article for specific thing which means that both a speaker and listener need to know about the thing they talk. If I see sentence like "the party has begun the painful process of rethinking its policies and strategy." it can be confused for the listener because the listener doesn't know which specific process is.

@MarkoBortas Yes, I said that in my answer, didn't I?  [please note corrections]: We often use the "the" article for specific things which means that both a speaker and listener need to know about the thing they are talking about. If I see a sentence like "the party has begun the painful process of rethinking its policies and strategy." it can be confusing for me as the listener because I don't know which specific process is being referred to. It's always about general/specific.

Oh, I thought that I'm the only one individual that get confused when the definite article is used without clear context, and my knowledge of a speaker's mind. But thank you!

@MarkoBortas You have to understand the difference between what you want to say [see my answer] and the other uses I pointed out. Do  you?
